# HAKUTO-R Mission length after landing?

Tags: the-moon, probe, lunar-landing

I was unable to find sources about what will happen to the current HAKUTO-R lunar lander after it lands in ± 4.5 months.

There are two possibilities coming to mind:

1. The lander won't survive the lunar night, meaning a surface mission of about 14 days.
2. The lander has heating elements that will keep it warm during the 14 day lunar night - those would need to be radioactive and Falcon 9 can't launch those.

So I assume it's option 1, is that correct?

Comment: the duration after landing is not even listed in the objectives of the mission, the final objective is just to land safely and contact Earth! https://ispace-inc.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/Successcriteria_scaled_en-2.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [German Wikipedia page for ispace](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ispace#Hakuto-R_(seit_2018)) says [translation mine]:

> The lander is reported to be 2.3 meters high and 2.7 meters wide and weighs approximately 1 t. ispace states the maximum payload capacity as 30 kg and the operations time on the Lunar surface as up to 12 days.

"Up to 12 days" seems to imply "up until the end of the Lunar day", but it is not explicitly stated.

Dubai's *Raschid* rover also seems to be designed to operate for one Lunar day.

Comment: thank you! as a german I'm now embarrassed to have not checked our own Wikipedia